# How to calculate Gregory series and the error with math.pi

Tags: python, pi

I need help with my code. I want to write a code that can calculate the error of "math.pi and pi using Gregory series". The range of error is `1.0E-1~1.0E-8`. Here is my code:

```
import math
EPSILON=0.1
def ans(terms):
    result=0.0
    for n in range(terms):
        result+=(-1.0)**n/(2.0*n+1.0)
    return 4*result
    if abs(pi-ans)<=EPSILON:
        print n,ans,abs(pi-ans)
    else:
        print("out of different")
```

I can get the ans, like `ans(60) >>> 3.1249271439289967`, but I can't get the output of `print n,ans,abs(pi-ans)`, what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your print statements are indented and it makes them part of your `ans()` function.
Your code has several other errors

- you can't use just `pi` but should use `math.pi`
- you call `ans` in your print statement without using argument

Your code should look like this :

```
import math
EPSILON=0.1
def ans(terms):
    result=0.0
    for n in range(terms):
        result+=(-1.0)**n/(2.0*n+1.0)

    return 4*result

n = 60
res = ans(n)
if abs(math.pi-res) <= EPSILON:
    print n,res,abs(math.pi-res)
else:
    print("out of different")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, pretty appreciate it.